# S3, cloudfront and expiry date

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I am using s3 to host static website. This website is placed in s3 bucket and being distributed by cloudfront. It all works well but we are facing problem when we need to change specific files. if we change index.html file in s3 bucket we are not getting the latest file from cloudfront. 
Should I be setting expiry time on s3 for these static files and only then after expired time will cloudfront look for new version of file and distribute new files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFront uses the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` header sent by the origin server to decide if a resource is to be stored in cache and how long a it is considered fresh. If you don't control caching via response headers, CF will consider each resource as stale after 24 hours it was fetched from the origin. Optionally, you can configure a distribution to ignore cache control headers and use an expiry time for each resource that you specify.

When you update a file at the origin, CF will not attempt to refresh its copy until it expires. You can follow different strategies to have CF update cached copies.

1) The least efficient and not recommended is use [invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html). You can do it via AWS console or API.

2) Tell CF when to look for updated content by sending `Expires` headers. For example, if you have a strict policy for deploying new content/version to your website and you know that say you roll out a deployment almost every Thursday, you may send an `Expires` header with each resource from your origin set to next planned deployment date. (This will probably not work with S3 origins.)

3) The most efficient and recommended way is to use [versioned URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ReplacingObjects.html). A good practice could be to include the last modified time of the resource in its access URI. With EC2 or other origins able to serve dynamic content it is fairly easy, with an S3 origin, it's not that straight forward if possible at all.

Therefore I'd recommend invalidating the updated resources.

Comment: Hello, can we set Cache-Control to no-cache for html files and will cloudfront always take latest html files?

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure how to control headers in a response sent by S3. It doesn't mean it's not possible, I just never used S3. But more importantly, if your S3 orgin always sends a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, it basically tells CF _not_ to store the given resource therefore every time it is requested from CF, it will forward the request to the origin to obtain it so you are _not_ benefiting the cloud at all.

Comment: I am planning to host a blog site on s3 and cf but some files like homepage and some category pages will need to be updated frequently other pages like blog single pages won't change often so i can set it to be cached but some html files like homepage and category pages I want not to be cached but get lates files everytime.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have to set the meta data on the s3 side:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

The best way I found to do this is use BucketExplorer and go "Batch Operation", "Update Metadata", "Add Metadata" and then add "Cache-Control:max-age=604800, public" a 1 week cache period.